# Expect for enable login

Tags: ssh, expect

I have a 3 password ( 18 char mandatory ) pwd authentication for my devices. Was hoping there is a way to set to go to privileged/enable mode via expect script . want to launch it like ssh 1.1.1.1 but with a script e.g. script 1.1.1.1.From 1 hour reading of the language,basically this is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

pwd = "my first pwd"
pwd2 = "my second pwd"
pwd3 = "third pwd"
spawn ssh $1
expect "yes/no" 
    send "yes\r"
    expect "*?assword" 
    send "pwd/r"
    expect ">"
    send "en/r"
    send "pwd2/r"
    expect "$"
    send "en/r"
    send "pwd3/r"
interact
```

Comment: And...what happens when you use that script? Does it work?

Comment: Nothing happens :) i think my error is within the variable ( passing the Ip and referncing it as $1 for exaple ) and the pwd hardcoding .

Comment: since you're new to Expect i'd like to suggest you take a look at [sexpect - Expect for Shells](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**. its usage is much easier than the Expect's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are making 3 mistakes:

1. expect is an extension of the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language and variables are set with the `set` command

   ```
   set pwd "my first pwd"
   ```
2. Tcl puts the command line arguments in the (0-indexed) `argv` array. You get the first argument with

   ```
   spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]
   ```
3. like the shell, you need to get the value of a variable with the `$var` syntax. Also, make sure you're using the correct backslash for the carriage return.

   ```
   send "$pwd\r"
   ```